# Ubuntu 20.4 login

Tags: 20.04

I can't login to Ubuntu 20.4 for unknown reasons. When it prompts for the password, I enter the password, and it looks like it is going to login, but unfortunately, it returns me to the login page again. Any hints, please? I don't want to lose the data.

Thanks in advance,